# Handle a POST response with RestKit that is not mapped to the POST object

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a situation where I am doing a post of an object (not a managed one, just an NSObject derived one), but the response from the REST API is not a JSON representation of the kind of object being posted. It is something else altogether. Is it possible to handle this?

Say I post an object (JSON):

```js
{
  "prop1" : 123,
  "prop2" : 5
}
```

And the response if not an object with properties `prop1` and `prop2`, as RestKit expects by default, but something else:

```js
{
  "data" : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  "message" : "hello world"
}
```

I've seen examples where operation.targetObject was set to nil, but (I believe) this is only in Core Data managed scenarios.

I am trying something simple like this:

```objc
RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [self.objectManager appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:body method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"items" parameters:nil];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
   // success is called, but the result does not contain what the response JSON is
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  // failure
}];

[operation setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock:^id(id deserializedResponseBody) {
    // deserializedResponseBody is always nil
}];

[operation start];
```

I thought I could be able to look at the response contents in the setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock, but it is always nil.

Because the posted object has `prop1` and `prop2` properties, and how RestKit works by default, it expects JSON with said properties. But, since the result has nothing to do with the posted object, `prop1` and `prop2` are just nil (which I don't care for anyway).

By the way, I have setup the request mapping correctly, so the `body` being passes in the operation object is correctly mapping my NSObject and sending it in the correct JSON format to the server.

Is there a way that I can make such a call with RestKit, and manually pull out what I am looking for on the success event? Even if it was a dictionary representation of the JSON response?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd just create a new object for your response and map your response to that.

### Objects

```
@interface MYRequest : NSObject

@property NSNumber *prop1;
@property NSNumber *prop2;

@end

@interface MYResponse : NSObject

@property NSArray *data;
@property NSString *message;

@end
```

### Mappings

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"prop1", @"prop2"]];

RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MYResponse class]];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"data", @"message"]];
```

### Descriptors

```
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                               objectClass:[MYRequest class]
                                                                               rootKeyPath:nil
                                                                                    method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                   pathPattern:@"items"
                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

### Object Manager

```
[self.objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
[self.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
```

### Execute

```
MYRequest *body = [MYRequest new];
[body setProp1:@123];
[body setProp2:@5];

[self.objectManager postObject:body
                          path:@"items"
                    parameters:nil
                       success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                           MYResponse *result = [mappingResult firstObject];
                           NSLog(@"Data: %@\nMessage: %@", [result data], [result message]);
                       }
                       failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                           NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                       }];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the source object into a dictionary and send that instead. Then the response data will naturally be mapped into a dictionary. This should be a minimal change to your mappings and a small change to the other code (using KVC `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Simply used below code

//If we received error message dictionary in API then we can convert RKObjectRequestOperation Data into Json dictionary 

 if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: operation.httpRequestOperation.responseData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
//here we can catch our error message..
let message:String = json["ErrorMessage"] as! String?
 print("Error Message: \(message)")
}
```